# salt-stack : No Top file or external nodes data matches found

Tags: python, saltstack

To test salt-stack I would like to copy a config file to another distant one (I am testing master and minion in localhost)

**/etc/salt/minion :**

```
master: 127.0.0.1
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/base
```

**/etc/salt/master:**

```
interface: 0.0.0.0
```

**The /srv/salt tree :**

```
 # tree srv/
srv/
├── salt
│   └── base
│       └── env
│           ├── envpy.template
│           └── init.sls
└── top.sls
```

**and the template file :**

```
# cat /srv/salt/base/env/envpy.template
This is a test !
```

**and this is the init file:**

```
#  cat /srv/salt/base/env/init.sls 

/home/myHome/env.py:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://base/env/envpy.template
```

**and finally the top file:**

```
# cat  /srv/salt/top.sls 
base:
  '*':
    - base.env
```

**Running salt highstate:**

```
# salt '*' state.highstate 
myHost:
----------
          ID: states
    Function: no.None
      Result: False
     Comment: No Top file or external nodes data matches found
     Started: 
    Duration: 
     Changes:   

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     1
```

Do you have any idea why I've got this error ?

Comment: just my 5 cents: if ChrisV's answer does not help, you might be struck by salt bug - it manifested for me when I updated salt-master (and minions afterwards). Before that - everything worked, after - I'm getting same issue. Stuff already tested, but no cigar: remove minion key from master and readd it, check master configs, restart salt-master and salt-minion processess, reboot master and nodes machines... Still to test: reinstall master, reinstall minions (maybe it has something to do with authentication credentials that are being generated dring install)

Comment: I have this problem now, Marek did you have any luck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paths are relative to your base (`/srv/salt/base`).

Try moving your top file to the 'base' directory. Also remove 'base' from the path in the file 'source' reference.

`file_roots` should be declared in `/etc/salt/master`

Comment: Also check `/var/log/salt/minion` for error messages, that can be caused by a missing `sls` file, like `Rendering exception occurred :Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'newrelic'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here. However, my cause was that the times/time zones were different between the master and minion.

After running dpkg-reconfigure tzdata on the minion, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  In my case there was a repeated minion wildcard pattern in the top.sls file.  Salt didn't tell me the file was bad, it said it was not present instead.