# saltstack configuration "No Top file or external nodes data matches found"

Tags: configuration, saltstack, yaml

A very similar version of this question is asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/645511/salt-stack-no-top-file-or-external-nodes-data-matches-found) , but it's completely different since the person had their top file in  the wrong directory.

I have 3 projects, that I'll call project1, project2, and project3.  My goal was to create a master/minion setup where my srv/salt directory looked like this:

```
/srv/salt
        |top.sls
        |/project1
                 |__/postgresql
                         |__init.sls
                         |__config.sql
                 |__/iptables
                         |__init.sls
                         |__config.sh
        |/project2
                 |__/tomcat
                         |__init.sls
                         |__config.sh
                 |__/java
                         |__init.sls
                         |__config.sh
        |/project3
                  |__/serverconfig
                         |__init.sls
                         |__config.sql
                 |__/conky
                         |__init.sls
                         |__config.sh
```

To accomplish this I edited /etc/salt/master to read

```
#/etc/salt/master
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
  project1:
    - /srv/salt/project1
  project2:
    - /srv/salt/project2
  project3:
    - /srv/salt/project3
```

I also wanted to have nodes set up since I have static servers that will be involved in each project, and that's a very intuitive way for me to organize them.

I started by editing /etc/salt/master to show my nodegroups

```
#/etc/salt/master
nodegroups:
  project1: 'L@project1_server1,project1_server2,project1_server3'
  project2: 'L@project2_server1,project2_server2,project2_server3'
  project3: 'L@project3_server1,project3_server2,project3_server3'
```

When running the once this was set up, I tried applying the project1 state to its servers by using the following command:

```
salt -N project1 state.highstate
```

This completes correctly for project1_server2, project1_server3, but fails on project1_server1.

The error for project1_server1 is "No Top file or external nodes data matches found"

I'm open to suggestions for how this setup could be more easily implemented, but I'd like to know the reason behind this not working. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT1**

adding my top.sls file

```
#/srv/salt/top.sls
project1:
  project1:
    - match: nodegroup
    - postgresql
    - iptables
project2:
  project2:
    - match: nodegroup
    - tomcat
    - java
project3:
  project3:
    - match: nodegroup
    - serverconfig
    - conky
```

**EDIT2**

Output from salt -N project1 grains.item id

```
project1_server1:
    ----------
    id:
        project1_server1
project1_server2:
    ----------
    id:
        project1_server2:
project1_server3:
    ----------
    id:
        project1_server3:
```

**EDIT3**

The correct answer was provided by ChrisV

The syntax errors for the node in /etc/salt/master were the problem.  I needed to change that, and then restart salt-master

```
pkill salt-master
salt-master -d
```

Comment: It would seem that project1_server1 is not matching it's nodegroup definition. I would start there (by verifying minion ID's). Also, it seems the nodegroup definition should be `project1: 'L@project1_server1,project1_server2,project1_server3'` per http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html

Comment: Changed my nodegroup and same problem, but thanks for linking to the docs.  Fixed that incorrect syntax

Comment: Can you append output from `salt -N project1 grains.item id` and `salt 'project1_server1' grains.item id`

Comment: edit2 is the output from the desired command

Comment: Did you restart master after making change to nodegroup in /etc/salt/master? Gotta ask ;)

Comment: And you should have asked, because that was the problem.  Thanks for the help.  The syntax problem for the node fixed it, but I forgot to restart salt-master.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to add an answser as the syntax problem, and restarting salt, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nodegroup definitions should be as follows:

`project1: 'L@project1_server1,project1_server2,project1_server3'`

Per Salt documentation: [Node Groups](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/nodegroups.html) and [Compound Matchers](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html)

Also note that a restart of the salt master daemon is required.